# Unable to access https endpoint of apache installed in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am running apache server within my ec2 instance and I am trying to access a static index.html. When I type http:// , I see the page displayed. However when I type https:// , the page isn't opening. Below is the security group setting. What am I missing?

> HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
>
> HTTP TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0
>
> Custom TCP Rule TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: What is in the Apache logs?

Comment: Did you setup Apache for SSL? This means setting up VirtualHost for 443, a2enmod ssl, installing a certificate, etc.

Comment: No , I did not setup Apache for ssl

Comment: you should enable ssl for your instance through httpd, here is the aws documentation about that:
[Configure Apache Web Server on Amazon Linux 2 to Use SSL/TLS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html)

Comment: Thanks @FadySaad..

Comment: Is it working correctly? @PunterVicky

Comment: I’ll try it out and update @FadySaad